# Word to describe "to talk excitedly about something"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for "to talk excitedly about something"? I'm sure there's a word for that. But [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/talk?s=t) didn't give me the answer.

Example sentence:

> Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd
>   been ______ for the past few days.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about *rave*? From M-W,

> [Definition of rave](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rave)
>   raved; raving
>   intransitive verb
>   1 c : to talk with extreme enthusiasm • *raved about its beauty*

Using the given example,

> Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd been **raving about** for the past few days.

Though I believe *rave* suggests that she's already tried it and now she wants to show John that it's great.

A somewhat informal alternative is *hype*. From Dictionary.com,

> [hype](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hype?s=t)
>   verb (used with object), hyped, hyping.
>   2. to create interest in by flamboyant or dramatic methods; promote or publicize showily:

Using the example,

> Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd been **hyping** for the past few days.

Comment: I second "...she'd been **raving about** for...". Good note that it suggests that Mary has already tried it.

Answer (score 8):

```
gush
ɡʌʃ/
verb
    2. Speak or write effusively or with exaggerated enthusiasm.
```

> Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd
>   been *gushing over* for the past few days.

Comment: This is the first one I thought of, too.

Comment: This seems like an older expression, as I've never heard anyone in my age group (18-28) say this.

Comment: The frequency of usage in print of "gushing over" and "gushing about" has remained roughly constant in the last 100 years, with a low around 1980 and increasing since. Take from that what you will.

Answer (score 5):

The first word that sprang to mind, on seeing the title, was

> jabber verb [NO OBJECT]
>
> ```
> Talk in a rapid, excited, and often incomprehensible way.
> ‘he jabbered on about football’
> ```
>
> noun
>
> ```
> Rapid, excited, and often incomprehensible speech.
> ```

Source https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jabber

Answer (score 4):

How about *enthuse*

> Express eager enjoyment, interest, or approval regarding something.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enthuse

Example:

> Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd been enthusing about for the past few days

Comment: This was my first thought on seeing the question title.

Answer (score 3):

You can say ".........she'd been raving about.......".  Enthusing about is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was *blather*.

> to talk foolishly at length —often used with *on*

So

> Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd been blathering on about for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

**To bubble.**

Mary took John to the place where they sold the banana splits she'd been **bubbling about** for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

Extolling?

To bless, carol, celebrate, emblazon, exalt, glorify, hymn, laud, magnify, praise, resound

Does change depending on how Mary feels about her own enthusiasm. Jabbering, going on about, blithering etc implies she's aware it's annoying. Or more something that John might say about her mentioning it so much. Raving is more neutral or enthusiastic. And something like extolling feels quite character dependent, if she's that sort of person...